# SVG path to Bézier Path in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on SVG and Bézier paths. It is very new to me . I want to make Bézier Path Animations from SVG Paths. Requirement is to animate any shape or letter like "A" "B" "C" and onward . Now i did not know that is it possible to make SVG path from some drawing tools and give these paths or files to Bézier paths (convert) in android..
Any help will be appreciated

[image: updated]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        View v = new SVGTest(this);

        setContentView(v);

    }
}
```

Comment: so you want some code that parses "d" attribute of path tag http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData ?

Comment: @pskink  i just asking that it is possible to convert svg paths to bezeir path or i can only use svg paths? Because i did not see any tutorial on converting SVG path to bezeier paths in android

Comment: sure it is posiible but. it depends how much features you need from svg standard

Comment: @pskink thankyou for the help,, but one thing more that your provided link contains information about how to make SVG paths it is helpful but can you have any infomartion about how to convert SVG paths to bezeir paths in android  or any small example or any tutorial of like you provided the link on SVG paths creation?

Comment: @pskink in tried out this sample code but its not working https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the below method "readPath" is an **ABSOLUTE MINIMUM** to converd SVG's path "d" attribute to android
Path, it supports only M, L, C and z commands but still i often use it with the output created by
Inkscape program:

```
class SVGTest extends View {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mTransformedPath;

    public SVGTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPath = new Path();
        mTransformedPath = new Path();
        String d = "M 30,11 C 30,20 20,25 15,30 C 11,24 1,19 1,11 C 1,3 13,1 15,10 C 15,1 30,3 30,11 z";
        readPath(d, mPath);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xff00aa00);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF();
        mPath.computeBounds(src, true);
        RectF dst = new RectF(30, 30, w-30, h-30);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.FILL);
        mPath.transform(matrix, mTransformedPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mTransformedPath, mPaint);
    }

    private void readPath(String data, Path p) {
        try {
            String[] tokens = data.split("[ ,]");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < tokens.length) {
                String token = tokens[i++];
                if (token.equals("M")) {
                    float x = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float y = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    p.moveTo(x, y);
                } else
                if (token.equals("L")) {
                    float x = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float y = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    p.lineTo(x, y);
                } else
                if (token.equals("C")) {
                    float x1 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float y1 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float x2 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float y2 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float x3 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    float y3 = Float.valueOf(tokens[i++]);
                    p.cubicTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
                } else
                if (token.equals("z")) {
                    p.close();
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("unknown command [" + token + "]");
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("bad data ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

test it by placing the following code in Activity.onCreate method:

```
View v = new SVGTest(this);
setContentView(v);
```

Comment: Please see image above.. your code also giving a huge white space.. if i am doing wrong please correct me..

Comment: what does your Activity onCreate method look like?

Comment: hmm, looks ok, but try to test it on v2.2 avd emulator as i did

Comment: Actually i want this functionality for Samsung Note 2 which also give Spen feature

Comment: try it on 2.2 just to see if it works or not, if it works then you will worry later

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42578/discussion-between-user42590-and-pskink)